# Will make install in the GNU build system overwrite previously installed binary files with the same name

Tags: gnu, gnu-make

My question regards the GNU build system, namely, the configure, make, make install build system.  My question regards "make install" specifically.  Let's say there is a bin directory a man directory etc. where I install all of my binaries and man pages.  What happens if there is a name clash.  For example what if there were a binary called program and then another package also has a binary called program?  When I do make install on the second program will it overwrite the first?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the "make install" command varies, but the short answer is essentially correct.  "make install" typically copies files from the build directory to some system directories, and those files would overwrite files that already existed in the destination directories.